# gganimate for random walk model

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, gganimate

I have created a random walk plot using ggplot2 (code below). I wondered if it would be possible to use the gganimate package so that the random walk process (the black line in the plot) gradually appears but stops once it touches the grey horizontal dashed line.

```
set.seed(3344)

create_random_walk <- function(number=500){
  data.frame(x = rnorm(number),
             rown = c(1:500)) %>%
    mutate(xt = cumsum(x))
}

randomwalkdata <- rbind(mutate(create_random_walk(), run = 1))

p <- ggplot(randomwalkdata, aes(x = rown, y = xt)) + 
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = '\nTime (arbitrary value)', y = 'Evidence accumulation\n') +
  theme_classic()

p + geom_segment(aes(x = 0.5, xend = 500, y = 25, yend = 25, linetype = 2), colour = "grey", size = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_linetype_identity()
```

[image]

Can anybody help?

Comment: By "stops once it touches the grey horizontal line," do you mean the animation should conclude at Time ~200, or that it should pause there before continuing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(gganimate); library(dplyr)
animate(
  ggplot(randomwalkdata |> filter(cumsum(lag(xt, default = 0) >= 25) == 0), 
       aes(x = rown, y = xt)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(rown == max(rown)), 
         size = 10, shape = 21, color = "red", stroke = 2) +
  labs(x = '\nTime (arbitrary value)', y = 'Evidence accumulation\n') +
  theme_classic() +
  annotate("segment", x = 0.5, xend = 500, y = 25, yend = 25, linetype = 2, 
               colour = "grey", linewidth = 1) +
  scale_linetype_identity() +
  transition_reveal(rown), 
  end_pause = 20, width = 600)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jon - this is great! Is there any way to add a circle (no fill but red outline) that appears when the black line touches the grey line?

Comment: Sure, you could add a layer that only has the last point, and make it a circle. See edit.

Comment: Ah great. Jon, please can I ask, which part of the code you have written above tells the black random walk line when to stop? Is there a way to make this stop earlier on in the process if desired?

Comment: `randomwalkdata |> filter(cumsum(lag(xt, default = 0) >= 25) == 0)` means "take the randomwalkdata, then filter it to only keep the data where the prior observations haven't yet exceeded 25." So ggplot2 is only receiving the data up to the first breach point.